# Charset UTF-8 (Doesn't work)

Tags: html, character-encoding

I've just uploaded my site to my server, and all the latin letters show as symbols.

I've tried all of these lines of code in the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

I also tried the ISO. Nothing works.

Any thoughts?

Comment: We can't see the code...

Comment: The actual data is not UTF-8 encoded or the HTTP headers declare another encoding, overriding the effect of the tags. This is very abstract, but it’s all we can say without further information.

Comment: can you paste some text that you think are displayed as symbols..

Answer (score 0):

write

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">  //inside head
</head>
```

Comment: The OP already had the meta tag. The code just wasn't formatted properly.

Comment: ya @NisseEngström you are right. i just want to focus on inside `head` tag

Comment: You might want to add the explanation of your solution to your answer itself.